# Javascript OOP and jQuery can't touch object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

How do i edit property variables from within jquery as shown in the example below:

```
function Timetable(){
    this.timetables=[];
    //get timetable data for currentUser
     $.get('http://someurl.com/api',function(data){
         this.timetables.concat($.parseJSON(data));
    });
}
```

What seems to happen is that the this.timetables seems to be out of the variable scope.

Comment: Please capitalize constructor names and use `[]` instead of `Array()` or `new Array()`.

Comment: It didn't even occur to me that this was a constructor at first.

Comment: My bad, new to all these conventions haha. But I will use them!

Comment: [This book](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Patterns-Stoyan-Stefanov/dp/0596806752) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `this`, you need to create a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

```
function timetable(){

  // create a closure
  var timetables = Array();

  //get timetable data for currentUser
  $.get('http://someurl.com/api',function(data){

    // this references the Array created above
    that.timetables = that.timetables.concat($.parseJSON(data));
  });
}
```

It just occurred to me that you may be using `timetable` to create objects.  As a side note, if that's the case, the convention is to call it `Timetable` for clarity.  If that's the case, use something like this.

```
function Timetable () {

  // store a reference to the scope
  var that = this;

  // create an instance property of the Timetable object
  this.timetables = [];

  $.get('http://someurl.com/api',function(data){

    // use our scope reference captured above
    // to update the timetables property
    that.timetables = that.timetables.concat($.parseJSON(data));
  }); 
}

var t = new Timetable();

// once the get call is complete
console.log(t.timetables);
```

Comment: Sorry, I goofed while editing.  It should now make more sense.

Comment: You were spot on with the object thing. I don't really know much about conventions haha (I'm new).

It doesn't throw any more errors, however it doesn't update the property. Console log shows: [] and also from the DOM inspector in firebog: []

Comment: Yeah, that's probably because you're evaluating before it's loaded.

Comment: Put the `console.log` part into the console after the get call completes.  Just open the console after the script runs at type `t.timetables`.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the jquery like Jivan says. The values do not change with this method.

I'm going to have to settle returning a value from my jquery function for now until I can find a cleaner solution

Comment: Bah, I'm too tired.  `that.timetables = that.timetables.concat($.parseJSON(data));`  Dur.

Comment: I see that works! Js variable scope is really confusing

Answer (score 1):

Force the scope.

`var scope = this;`

Then you can use scope inside instead of "this" from jQuery

Answer (score 1):

It's because inside your callback function, the scope of `this` is not the same. **It now refers to the object bound to your callback function** (`$` in this case).

Earlier answers to your question already advised you on a concrete way out of your trouble, so I'm not of much help there.

But if you want a (very) detailed and absolutely worth-reading answer about this topic in a broader sense, [you should definitely read this post (see the accepted answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword).

[This other one about closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) (what you seem to need here) could also be of great help.